# CSS Sprites - How to hide the balance portion of the image

Tags: php, html, css, css-sprites

Hi I am using an Image Sprite to display various Icons.

**XHTML**

```
<div class="ListIcons">
    <ul>
    <li class="Icon i-scissors">A list item using the <strong>i-scissors</strong> class.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.Icon {background:url(../images/icons/icons.png) no-repeat top left;}
.i-scissors{ background-position: 0 -52px; width: 32px; height: 32px; }
```

**The issue**

[image]

**My Question**

How can I hide the other two images which are being displayed along with the one I want.

Kindly Help !

The Sprite

The Sprite Image which I am using is this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have modified the code a little

**HTML**

```
<div class="ListIcons">
    <ul>
    <li class="i-scissors">A list item using the <strong>i-scissors</strong> class.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
li.i-scissors {

    list-style: none outside none;
}
li.i-scissors:before {
    background: url(../images/icons/icons.png) no-repeat scroll 0 -52px transparent;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 23px;
    height: 32px;
    top: 11px;
    left: 19px;
}
```

**Output would look like**

[image: list sprite]

You can make changes to the css as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You must make another node for your icon, something like this

```
 <ul>
<li class="some_class"><span class="Icon i-scissors"></span>A list item using the <strong>i-scissors</strong> class.</li>
</ul>
```

If you look your css there is `witdh` and `height` are `32px` but your sting is long inside,  `<li>` so divide it inti two part

Comment: Alternatively, the `:before` pseudo-element might be useful here and will keep the source cleaner. (Not available in IE up to 7, IIRC)